# Trying to send List object to another activity

Tags: android

I am trying to send a `List<Question>` to other activity but I am receiving the error "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable".

FirstActivity

```
    List<Question> list;
    list = response.body().items;
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, RestaurantActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("restaurants", (Parcelable) list); 
    SearchActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

SecondActivity

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    List<Question> restaurants = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("restaurants");
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(restaurants.get(0).title);
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that `ArrayList` itself does not implement the `Parcelable` interface. However, some Android classes like `Intent` and `Bundle` have been set up to handle `ArrayList`s provided that the instances they contain are of a class which does implement `Parcelable`.

So, instead of `putExtra`, try using the [`putParcelableArrayListExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String%2C%20java.util.ArrayList%3C%3F%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)) method instead.

You'll need to use get [`getParcelableArrayListExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String)) on the other side.

Be aware that this only works with `ArrayList`s, and the `Question` class will need to implement `Parcelable`.

Comment: I can't, I receive this error:
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.List<com.example.xxx.Question>', required: 'java.util.ArrayList<? extends android.os.Parcelable>

Comment: Right - make sure that you're passing an `ArrayList`, not a `List`, and that `Question` implements the `Parcelable` interface.

Comment: also list is just an interface pass arraylist instead. am i right?